# drracket flip over the remove function

Tags: scheme, racket

i have 2 lists

```
(define wholelist '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10))
(define list1 '(3 4 6 9 10))

(define (removelist list1 list2)
        (remove* list1 list2))
```

what i want to do is, if i

```
(define result1 (removelist list1 wholelist)
> '(1 2 5 7 8)
```

but i want the result list as

```
> '(3 4 6 9 10)
```

using the remove* function.

is there any way that i can flip over my '(1 2 5 7 8) result as '(3 4 6 9 10)??
like

```
(not (remove* list1 list2))
```

????

thank you so much for your help!

also, is there any way to define a list inside of cond statement or a function???

thank you so much!

Comment: Are your lists _always_ guaranteed to be in ascending order? If so, there's a faster solution to this (than Óscar's answer, which does not require the lists to be ordered but is slower).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, [`filter`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) will be more useful than [`remove*`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._remove%2A%29%29): we want to obtain all the elements in `wholelist` which are also [member](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._member%29%29)s of `list1`. Try this:

```
(filter (lambda (e) (member e list1))
        wholelist)
=> '(3 4 6 9 10)
```

Of course we can do something similar using `remove*`, but it's less natural:

```
(remove* (filter-not (lambda (e) (member e list1))
                     wholelist)
         wholelist)
=> '(3 4 6 9 10)
```

Regarding your other question:

> Is there any way to define a list inside of `cond` statement or a function?

Sure, use a [`let`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/let.html) expression, or local `define`s. For instance:

```
(define (my-function x)
  (let ((my-list '(1 2 3 4 5)))
    <do something with my-list>))
```